# Hyperledger container creation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am setting up first network in hyper ledger fabric. while starting the network after creating all the MSP and Channel artifacts (successfully). the containers for the orderer and peer organisations are getting created whereas CLI container is not getting with the error saying it is already in use. Following error messages attached.

Please help.

> ERROR: for cli  Cannot create container for service cli: b'Conflict.
>   The container name "/cli" is already in use by container
>   "cc7fcff80a7e19f4bb74791af556f6e57f5021c136ad3ca70b5eaff2f9d4bd12".
>   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.'

Comment: run the command "docker ps" to check running container.

Comment: If cli container is running kill it first.

Comment: i figured out that I need to remove (rm) all the stopped container and recreate/restart the images. But as soon as I do that some of the peers , orderer container are exiting immediately and only few are kept running.  Is it something to do with memory  ? any help will be appreciated !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following command in order to remove only the cli container:

docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | grep cli | awk '{print $1}')